# Laravel 5, View::Share

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to do a `view::share('current_user', Auth::User());` but in laravel 5 i can't find where to do this, in L4 you could do this in the baseController, but that one doesn't exists anymore.

grt Glenn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you can probably create your own BaseController and extend it in other controllers.

Second thing is, that you may use `Auth:user()` directly in View, you don't need to assign anything in the view.

For other usages you can go to `app/Providers/App/ServiceProvider.php` and in `boot` method you can `View::share('current_user', Auth::User());` but of course you need to add importing namespaces first:

```
use View;
use Auth;
```

because this file is in `App\Providers` namespace

Answer (score 15):

I am using Laravel 5.0.28, `view::share('current_user', Auth::User())` doesn't work anymore because this issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6130

What I do instead is, first create a new service provider using artisan.

```sh
php artisan make:provider ComposerServiceProvider
```

Then add ComposerServiceProvider to `config/app.php` providers array

```php
//...
'providers' => [
    //...
    'App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider',
]
//...
```

Then open `app/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php` that just created, inside boot method add the following

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('*', function($view)
    {
        $view->with('current_user', Auth::user());
    });
}
```

Finally, import `View` and `Auth` facade

```php
use Auth, View;
```

For more information, see http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Comment: According to that issue, "In the boot function, the Auth::user() hasn't been initialized yet so it is being shared to the view as null." That is actually happening to me; Auth::user is null. How is it working for you?

Comment: @Vic Yes, I happened to the problem, what is your solution?

Comment: @iatboy I don't quite remember what I was trying to accomplish here, but I  just go with using ``Auth::user()`` directly in the view as in the accepted answer. No need to pass it on from elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5 uses the same method as in laravel 4:

```
View::share('current_user', Auth::User());
```

or using the view helper:

```
view()->share('current_user', Auth::User());
```

See in http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views

Answer (score 4):

This will may help:

```
App::booted(function()
{
    View::share('current_user', Auth::user());
});
```

Comment: under the register function

Answer (score 2):

I'v tried it, put it in app/Providers simply not working. The alternative way is to create a Global middleware and put View::share('currentUser', Auth::user()); there.

Comment: In vue component, How can access all key in all view component based on View::Share functionality.