# How to share Auth::user among all views in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to share the currently logged in user to all views. I am attempting to use the `view->share()` method within `AppServiceProvider.php` file.

I have the following:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {


    public function boot(Guard $guard)
    {
        view()->share('guard', $guard);
        view()->share('user', $guard->user());
    }

    //..
}
```

However, when I hit up a view (after logging in), the `user` variable is null. Strangely, the `$guard->user` (the protected attribute, not the public method user()) is not. The output I get is the following:

[image]

Note the guard->user variable is populated, but the user variable is null.

Comment: What do you get if you call the `check()` and the `getUser()` methods?

Comment: `check()` returns `false` and `getUser()` returns `NULL`

Comment: I feel like its "checking" too early, but apparently the `boot` method is suppose to wait to all services have registered and right to go

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Better off using View Composers for this one.

In your ComposerServiceProvider in `boot()`:

```
view()->composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\GlobalComposer');
```

In HTTP/ViewComposers create a class GlobalComposer, and create the function:

```
public function compose( View $view )
{
    $view->with('authUser', Auth::user());
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Comment: I see view composers as something very powerful, but (a) I want to use the injected Guard, not the facade Auth, and (b) the `view()->share` usecase is essentially what I am using it for.. Although, for other parts of this project i will be using view composers.

Comment: Can you share the specific reason you want to use an injected Guard vs the facade?

Comment: Correction - upon further research, you are right. This is due to this "bug" https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6130   This answer on SO explains it better than I: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29817941/614112

Comment: @SebBarre my guess is testability. Injecting things where necessary makes a lot more sense, particularly if it's doable (such as in composers).

Comment: one thing to be aware of with `*` view composers is that it will be executed for every `view` on the page, which means every included view, not just the main one. while this won't have a huge impact for `Auth::user()`, be very wary of executing database calls in here.

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this problem without creating a file.

Add these codes to boot() action of your ServiceProvider and that's it.

```
view()->composer('*', function($view){
  $view->with('user', Auth::user());
});
```

Source also same: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Look **Wildcard View Composers**.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks!