# Laravel variable used by all views within appserviceprovider

Tags: laravel, global-variables

I was wondering if there’s a way to share a collection with all views in the appserviceprovider.  I have several views that are utilized by a lot of pages and they all require getting the users the zip code and the related geo-location information.  As opposed to running this query in every view, I was hoping there would be a simpler way, unfortunately might rise were not successful. Everything I found related to global shares with views, not within the appserviceprovider which is where I need to use it. I would like $t1 to be available in all views. Thanks for your help!

```
    view()->composer('common.new.restaurants', function($view)
    {
        $t1=loc_zip::where('zip',auth()->user()->last_zip)->first();
        $view->with(['r'=>$r]);
    });


    view()->composer('common.categories.restaurants', function($view)
    {
        $t1=loc_zip::where('zip',auth()->user()->last_zip)->first();
…
            $view->with(['r'=>$r,'a'=>$a]);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, as explained here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

This post goes deeper into the issue [Laravel 5, View::Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275820/laravel-5-viewshare)

Comment: I looked at all this... I'm using Laravel 5.4. One potential answer in there had a chance, but I've tried these, they share with views - not with the appserviceproviders